# Laravel connecto to MySQL with no database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In Laravel is possible to connect to MySQL without selecting database? I want to connect to host without DB and then create database from artisan script.

Comment: But why? Of course you can use `DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE :schema', ['schema' => $schemaName]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the database does not exist, it does not mean that Laravel is unable to create it or manage this situation.

Just add in the configuration the database name you wish to use, then run the migration that create your database with all your columns and tables.

Comment: It's also possibile to create a user to MySQL host?

Comment: Not with Laravel migrations. For what purpose are you doing this, anyway? Testing?

Comment: Yes for testing. I write this code: `DB::statement("CREATE USER '?'@'?' IDENTIFIED BY '?';", [$db_username, $host, $db_password]);` But I receive a general error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1396 Operation CREATE USER failed for '?'@'?'

Comment: Why not using an in-memory database instead?

Comment: I want to create a new DB user for each database that I create via code